# java recursion for DOM objects

Tags: java, xml, recursion

I have to search for specific element in DOM Structure recursively, but right now I am completely "stuck" and cannot find where my algorithm is mistaken.

Alg searches for element table and has to return true if it is exists.

```
private boolean isCompositeExists(Node fieldNode) {
   NodeList childNodes = fieldNode.getChildNodes();
   if (childNodes != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
         Node child = childNodes.item(i);

         isCompositeExists(child);

         if (child.getNodeName().equals("table")) {
            return true;
         }

      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you discarding the return value from the recursive call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need something like:

```
private boolean isCompositeExists(Node fieldNode) {
  NodeList childNodes = fieldNode.getChildNodes();
  for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
     Node child = childNodes.item(i);
     if (child.getNodeName().equals("table") || isCompositeExists(child)) {
        return true;
     }
  }
   return false;
}
```

Note that you do not need to check `getChildNodes()` for `null`.